# watchOS minimum padding too much

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

I am trying to recreate the messages view on the Apple Watch. This is how it looks like. 
[image]

However, whatever I try, I can't seem to get rid of the pre-set padding the WKInterfaceLabels come with. Even the padding that you get in the "real" app is too much for me, I'd love to do something like negative padding.

I tried the containing group's `spacing` argument, I tried putting the labels into groups and I tried going with setting a fixed-height manually, which helped a little bit but eventually starts cutting off letters like 'g' at the bottom but leaves lots of space at the top. Is there a way to change that?
[image]